# How can I use cron4j to utilize dao methods an a log4j to log what is happening meanwhile?

Tags: java, mysql, log4j, dao, scheduler

In my project I have written the DAO-s and I want to use a scheduler that will call a DAO.delete() method every week for some of the tables of my mysql database. And in case any exceptions is caught and when the task has finished I want log4j to have stored in a table called logs, every possible log of events that occurr related to data through the DAOs... I have implemented a connection pool ... how do other threads of the cron4j scheduler and log4j scheduler affect (if they do) the concurrency of the connections of the database? ...

Please feel free to advice as much as you can with this problem ...

many thanks in advice ...

Comment: Do you use one connection per thread or you share db connections between threads? Btw show your code.

Comment: Considered using a container like Spring? it will have connection pooling and will help resolving concurrency issues